# Type transmutation of von Neumann factors

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

The crossed product of a Type $III_{1}$ von Neumann factor with its modular automorphism group is generically Type $II$. Does there exist a similar construction turning a Type $II$ (or a Type $III_{1}$) into a Type $I$?